# Finding all matching entries in an array of dicts in Python 3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm using Python 3.8. I would like to find entries in an array of dictionaries that match a certain condition. I tried this:

```
>>> results = [{'title': 'hello'}, {'title':'hello', 'a':'b'}]
>>> orig_title = "hello"
>>> next(d for d in results if d['title'].lower() == orig_title.lower())
{'title': 'hello'}
```

but it only seems to find the first matching entry. Also, it seems unable to terminate gracefully when no matching entries are found:

```
>>> orig_title = "hello2"
>>> next(d for d in results if d['title'].lower() == orig_title.lower())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

What's a better way to rewrite the above to only find matching dictionaries in a list that match a particular condition?

Comment: `next` gives the *next* one, not all of them. What output were you expecting? If you want e.g. a list of all of them, use `list` (or just a list comprehension) instead.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: that looks like an answer.

Comment: @deltab I'd rather wait for the OP's expectation to be clear. If they're asking how to get a *list* instead of the *next* value, it seems tautological, that surely can't be what they're asking.

Comment: Literally just delete the four characters that keep you from having an iterable with the results you want.

Comment: This isn't Reddit, we don't have subs. If you find your questions are attracting downvotes, there's advice at [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just looping over the results:

```
results = [{'title': 'hello'}, {'title': 'hello', 'a': 'b'}]
orig_title = "hello"

res = (d for d in results if d['title'].lower() == orig_title.lower())

for r in res:
    print(r)
```

Producing:

```
{'title': 'hello'}
{'title': 'hello', 'a': 'b'}
```